# Subnav impossible to hover because of CSS style

Tags: html, css

I have to add a subnav in an existing nav using a CSS style to reach php page.

Existing nav was : `nav > ul > li > a href (ok)`

I did:

```
 nav > ul > li > a href (ok)
 nav > ul > li > ul > li > a href (ko)
```

I actually can't hover href (ko) with the cursor : items subnav disappear !
I search in CSS style but I don't really understand how it's works.

I want to click on the 2 pages linked in subnav bellow :
`accountCustomerAll.php` and `serviceViewAll.php`.

If you have an idea...

Here is my HTML code :

```css
/* Nav Meu Styling */
.nav-menu li a {
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; }
  .nav-menu li a.active, .nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: #0093df !important; }

.nav-menu li:hover > a {
  color: #000; }

.nav-menu > li {
  margin-left: 30px; }

.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 28px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  background: #fff; }

.nav-menu ul li {
  transition: 0.3s; }

.nav-menu ul li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #333;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: none; }

.nav-menu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #0093df; }

.nav-menu ul ul {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0; }
```

```html
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li><a>Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="accountCustomerAll.php">Consulter les clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="serviceViewAll.php">Consulter les commandes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you share a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) or similar to see the issue?

Comment: No I don't unfortunally. The issue is the cursor hand icon switchs on arrow icon when I want to click on the link for 2 php pages.

Comment: I [created one](https://codepen.io/ces/pen/LYGweJJ) and I can't reproduce the issue with the information that you got. Why do you use `<a href=\"\">` instead of `<a href="">`?

Comment: So it seems to come from an other file maybe...

Comment: The code is in a php variable in a php page. There are some differents header  for differents profil's user

Comment: You give me an idea : I deleted href=\"\"> before in the main menu without link and now I can reach the submenu !

Comment: Here is my new code :

Comment: <nav id=\"nav-menu-container\">
     <ul class=\"nav-menu\">
      <li><a href=\"index.html\">Accueil</a></li>
      <li><a>Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href=\"accountCustomerAll.php\">Consulter les clients</a></li>
         <li><a href=\"serviceViewAll.php\">Consulter les commandes</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>

Comment: I test even more : if I add style in this link, it doesn't work anymore ! For exemple this code produce the error like at the begining :

Comment: <li><a style=\"color:   #222222\">Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>

Comment: The good code is :

Comment: <li><a>Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>

Comment: The wrong code was :

Comment: <li><a href=\"\">Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>

Comment: Please, edit the original question to add these details. Avoid the comments to add code, it's difficult to read it.

Comment: It is the first time I ask a question and I don't manage to edit correctly my post to add some more code.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I modified my original code with the correction because I didn't manage to add the new one. Now it's run.

Comment: It's resolved but I don't know if i have to do something more about this post.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can publish an answer with your solution. Maybe it could help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful for you. You have to apply different `css` on inner `<ul>`.

```css
/*   /* Nav Meu Styling */
        .nav-menu li {
            float: left;
            list-style: none;           }

        .nav-menu li a {
            padding: 0px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #222222;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        }

        .nav-menu li a.active,
        .nav-menu li a:hover {
            color: #0093df !important;
        }

        .nav-menu li:hover>a {
            color: #000;
        }

        .nav-menu>ul {
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
            background: #fff;
        }

        .nav-menu ul li {
            transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 75%;
        }

        .nav-menu ul li a {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: #333;
            transition: 0.3s;
            display: block;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: none;
        }

        .nav-menu ul li:hover>a {
            color: #0093df;
        }

        .nav-menu ul ul {
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .sub-menu {
            display: none;
        }

        .sub-menu>li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
        }

        ul.nav-menu li a:hover+ul.sub-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        ul.sub-menu:hover {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
 <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a>Gérer l'Aérodrome</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="accountCustomerAll.php">Consulter les clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="serviceViewAll.php">Consulter les commandes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>`.nav-menu li a.active, .nav-menu li a:hover{ color: #0093df !important;}`</s>

Buggy :active, should be:

```
.nav-menu li a:active, .nav-menu li a:hover{ color: #0093df}
```

Please, don't use `!importand`, debug instead.
Nested structures are hard to maintain, easier would be

```
<ul><li>  <ol><li> ... </li></ol></li></ul>
```

it is absolutely allowed to style `<ol>` without numbers.

Comment: Thank you both for your response. Sorry I just see them now. I noticed yours solutions (sub-menu or not use "!important" keyword) don't change the result if I use or don't use it. A strange problem occurs : the menu is showed because a command "echo $header" in php but I need to refresh the html page (with Ctrl + F5) to see the arrow on the right of main menu item ("Gere l'aerodrome") to access to submenu. If I don't do that, it is the same problem at the begining. I don't solve this new problem yet.

Comment: For Sohail Ahmed : In CSS I added these 4 items from your code : "sub-menu", "sub-menu>li", "ul.nav-menu li a:hover+ul.sub-menu ", "ul.sub-menu:hover" and I added "<ul class="sub-menu"> in html code. I don't know if it is enought, it is hard for me to compare what's change between my code and yours, but I see no difference in the behavior.